# spring integration: service activator requires-reply="false" usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Why am I receiving the below exception even after I've specified `requires-reply="false"`

**Exception**

*org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available*

**Config**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.1.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inChannel">

    </int:channel>

    <bean id="upperService" class="sipackage.service.UppercaseService"></bean>

    <int:service-activator requires-reply="false" input-channel="inChannel" ref="upperService" method="toUpper"></int:service-activator>
</beans>
```

**JUnit**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/META-INF/spring/integration/sample.xml"})
public class ChannelTest {

    @Autowired MessageChannel inChannel;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        boolean sendOutcome=inChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello, there 1!").build());
        assertTrue(sendOutcome);

        sendOutcome=inChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello, there 2!").build());
        assertTrue(sendOutcome);
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
public class UppercaseService {

public String toUpper(String msg)
{
    return msg.toUpperCase();
}
}
```

Comment: you mean the client is not interested in the returned value of the downstream service? use output-channel="nullChannel"; requires-reply should be for methods returning void or null afaik

Comment: Thank you but I am aware of both the solutions you have suggested. I thought requires-reply flag was meant to ignore the returned value. If not what might be the purpose of this flag?

Comment: requires-reply is false by default. set the requires-reply attribute of the downstream component to 'true' to ensure a timely response as produced by the throwing of an Exception as soon as that downstream component does return null internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per ["Configuring Service Activator"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator-namespace):

> when the service method returns a non-null value, the endpoint will
>   attempt to send the reply message to an appropriate reply channel. To
>   determine the reply channel, it will first check if an
>   "output-channel" was provided in the endpoint configuration... If no
>   "output-channel" is available, it will then check the Message's
>   replyChannel header value.

What it doesn't mention there is that the basic behavior of any reply-producing message handler is that if it doesn't find anything with those two checks, it throws an exception, as can be seen in [the sendReplyMessage() method](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java#L188) of the AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler, a base class shared by many such things. Thus if you have a non-void service method, you either have to set an output-channel or a replyChannel header on your messages.

One option [suggested by the SI guys](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132455-Override-a-quot-default-quot-reply-channel&p=431269#post431269) is to put a header-enricher in front of your service activator that will set the replyChannel header to "nullChannel". Because headers aren't overwritten by default, any existing replyChannel will work as intended, and everything else will be dumped to the nullChannel.

As for the requires-reply attribute, that's for handling an entirely different problem where you have a component that might produce `null` instead of a valid messages. That flag allows you to indicate that a `null` response should be turned into an exception. You'll find a discussion of this in the note on ["Messaging Gateway Error Handling"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-error-handling) and in ["Gateway behavior when no response arrives"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#d4e3326).

Answer (score 7):

`requires-reply="false"` means "it's OK that a method that is not defined to return `void` returns `null`".

IF the method DOES return a reply, we need someplace to send it. As `guido` said - if you want to ignore the result, set the `output-channel` to nullChannel.

Answer (score 0):

**Attribute** : requires-reply

Specify whether the service method must return a non-null value. 
 This value will be 'false' by default, but if set to 'true', a 
 ReplyRequiredException will be thrown when the underlying 
 service method (or expression) returns a null value.